# Why the v-text-field which type is number that is still can type "abc' into it when is used in firefox?

Tags: vue.js, firefox, vuetify.js

vuetify 2.5.1

vue 2.6.12

firefox dev_editon 90.0b1

---

```
<v-text-field v-model.number="data" type="numebr" :min="0"/>
//or 
<v-text-field v-model.number="data" type="numebr" min="0"/>
```

Is it a bug of vuetify?

When I click back key, the data will be '' which is string-type.

and I set the min property to the v-text-field but I still can input negative number into this v-text-field?

How can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, I think there is a typo `numebr`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `v-text-field` to accept numbers as:

```
<v-text-field type="number" min="0"/>
```

Comment: I try to just set min="0" but still I can type  negative number into it.

Comment: Can you update your code in the question?